# Order older than 18 months on Best Buy

Tags: bestbuy.com

Is there any way to see orders that are older than 18 months in my Best Buy account?

I can't find any option for it but I don't know whether this is a limitation from the website or because I don't have any order that are older than 18 months.

[image: Account example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to see orders that are older than 18 months in a BestBuy account.